# Comparing the elements of an array in 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

I need to compare the first element of an array with the last element and so on. It is something like i have an array A[9] (of size 10). So i need to compare A[0] with A[9] and if A[0] > [9] then i need to **subtract them** to store it in another array. The process goes on with A[1] to A[8], A[2] to A[7] until it reaches A [4] to A[5]
I have the program broken down in C but i don't really know how to proceed with this in assembly language.

It is easier to compare two different variables. But if anyone can show me how how to compare different elements of a same array it will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as "array" in assembler. All you've got is memory addresses and loaded values in registers. So, make "esi" point to the address of first array element, "edi" to the last one and work it out from there.

Comment: I don't have time to work out a full answer, but I'd try to solve this with some string prefix instructions (rep): http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/rep.htm These instructions repeat operations on a string of bytes until ending is reached. I think that's what you need. Note, that in the link I referred some of the instructions are 80386 and up. Are you really tied to 8086 only?

Comment: @CsabaToth : unfortunately yes, we are only being taught 8086 in college at the moment

Comment: Assembler arrays are declared using db (bytes), dw (words), dd (double words, or dq (quad words). Since this 8086, you'll probably have an array of bytes or words such as | mybytes db 1,2,3,4 | or | mywords dw 1,2,3,4 | . For MASM and ML, "sizeof" gets the size of an array in bytes, and "lengthof" gets the number of elements.

Comment: @rcgldr i am using TASM. 
i have already declared the arrays as A db 10(?) and B db 5 (?).
 I have also created a loop to enter 10 numbers. I am stuck in the part where i need to compare the first element, that is A[0] with A[9] and if A[0] is greater than A[9] then subtract them and store the result in B[0].
I have created like 1/4th till the entering of 10 elements via a cmp and jmp statements but i am not sure how to compare the elements stored in the same array.

Comment: Use BX as an index. If it's array of bytes, then BX is incremented by 1 to go through the array, if it's an array of words, the BX is incremented by 2. Example load instruction: MOV AX,array[BX].

Comment: If you have it written in C, then just use the C compiler option that outputs assembly language to a listing file. Even if the C compiler outputs 32-bit assembly, it will (in general) be very similar to the 8086 code. You can use the generated assembly to give you an idea of how to proceed with the 8086 assembly language version.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to simply move the " di" to last index of the array and point "si" to the first index of the array
and then you have to compare the contents of the si and the di by the dereference operator [] and incremement the si and decrements the di
for example:
.data
array db 1,2,3,4,5,6
.code
mov ax,@data
mov dx,ax

mov si,offset array

mov di,offset array

add di,5

; di will now point to the last index you can also do it                                           ;with a loop if the array is taken as input and is very large
mov cx,6

loop1:

mov al,[si]

cmp al,[di]

;here are the condition which you wanna do if these values are equal of unequal ;or above or below etc

inc si

dec di

loop loop1

exit:

mov ah,4ch

int 21h

end